# View contains another view and touchEvent

Tags: android, events

So, I have a `View` which contains another `View`. I want the parent view to catch the event `TouchEvent` and it will decide according to a certain criteria if to propagate the event to the child-view or cancel it.

I tried at the `onTouchEvent` of the parent to `return true` but it still propagated to the child-view. Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a child view receives the TouchEvent before the parent view does. If this is indeed the case, you should define the criteria in the child view onTouchEvent listener.